# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: -1; expected: 1

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, netbeans

I am new to Hibernate.
I am using NetBeans 7.4 , Hibernate 4.3.6 and Database as Ms Sql Server.
It works fine for fetching data from database but it gives error for Insert , Update , Delete.
My Hibernate Configuration file as :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://SqlSer:1433;databaseName=HibSample</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SA</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="Entity/Sample.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my HibernateUtil File is as:

```
public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

My Reverse Engineering File as:

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="HibSample" match-schema="dbo"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Sample"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

My Pojo and Mapping Files are :

```
public class Sample  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int id;
     private String fullName;
     private String address;

    public Sample() {
    }


    public Sample(int id, String fullName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public Sample(int id, String fullName, String address) {
       this.id = id;
       this.fullName = fullName;
       this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entity.Sample" table="Sample" schema="dbo" catalog="HibSample">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="fullName" type="string">
            <column name="FullName" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="string">
            <column name="Address" length="50" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Main File is :

```
public class Main 
{
    public Main(){};

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{

            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Sample s = new Sample();
            s.setId(3);
            s.setFullName("Demo");
            s.setAddress("Demo");

            Sample s1 = (Sample)session.load(Sample.class, 2);
            System.out.println("ID :"+s1.getId());
            System.out.println("Full Name : "+s1.getFullName());
            System.out.println("Address : "+s1.getAddress());

            session.save(s);

            if(!tx.wasCommitted())
            {
                tx.commit();
            }            

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if(tx != null)
            {
                tx.rollback();
                ex.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Table Data are as follow :

```
ID  Full Name Address
1   XYZ       India
2   ABC       India
```

Error IS :

```
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Entity/Demo.hbm.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Entity/Sample.hbm.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:42 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://150.10.10.233;databaseName=HibSample]
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=SA, password=****}
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Result

```
ID :2
Full Name : ABC
Address : India

Hibernate: insert into HibSample.dbo.Sample (FullName, Address, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: -1; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at UI.Main.main(Main.java:45)
Dec 17, 2014 4:42:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I have search all possibilities but can't find the solution.

Comment: Try to mark your method with @Transactional notation and remove beginTransaction and commit in the method

Comment: Is it possible with desktop application?

Comment: When you are trying to save, hibernate is thinking that you are trying to update. Instead of .save() try .saveOrUpdate()

Comment: I have tried saveOrUpdate() , but it's not working.

Comment: I have tried with MySql and it's working perfectly , so is it the problem with Ms Sql Server ?